# How to find a "near LCM" of multiple numbers or common multiples with the least remainder that isn't zero

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure if I am explaining this right but basically I am trying to figure out a "near LCM".

If I have $9$ pears, $3$ apples and $4$ bananas the LCM is $36$. But there is a "near LCM" in $9$, where $3\cdot3=9$, $9\cdot1=9$ and $4\cdot2=8$, leaving a remainder of $1$. I am trying to determine that "near LCM" as well as the remaining amount. I know how to find the LCM, but I'm not sure how to calculate a "near LCM" where I could capture the remainder amount. I would want this amount to be the smallest remainder closest to the LCM.

My brain is having trouble thinking how to do this and I will be applying this as a php function to do the calculations. Thanks for any and all help.

Another member explained it as:

Find a positive number $N$ which is least that satisfies $N\equiv0,1,2\pmod{a_i}$ where $a_i$ are your given numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use MathJax.

Comment: In order to help make your question more precise, is there a specific distance away you'll allow a near-LCM to be? I see at the bottom you've written $N\equiv0,1,2\pmod{a_i}$ where the $a_i$ are the given numbers; is $2$ the maximum distance away or do you want it to be specified in your function?

Comment: I've edited your question using our site's standards for MathJax. If possible, please ensure that it still captures the same meaning as what you originally intended.

Comment: @Clayton the maximum amount would be 10,000. Let me know if I can provide any other information to make my question more clearer

Comment: I guess as a last question as far as I understand the question: is finding the LCM too computationally intense? Since you're wanting to apply this as a php function, I'm guessing you want the algorithm to be as efficient as possible, but it might just be that you're wanting to be able to work with smaller numbers as opposed to (potentially) very large numbers.

Comment: @clayton finding the LCM isn't too intense, but for my application larger numbers are not helpful. Usually the array I am passing in contains 20-50 numbers which results in a very large LCM, that's why if I can find something thats close, that isn't astronomically large, it's alot more usable for my application. 10,000 would be max, but ideally it'd be under 1000.

Comment: If by "close", you mean distance, then the member's explanation isn't complete as it only considers positive congruences. Instead, you want to find a positive integer $N$ which satisfies a set of conditions like $N \equiv -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 \pmod{a_i}$, for a maximum distance of $2$, or even just $1$ which would be $N \equiv -1, 0, 1 \pmod{a_i}$. If, for whatever reason, you have a preference or requirement for allowing more positive values, then you may wish to add $1$ or $2$ more positive congruences to the allowed values. Also, you may whish to limit based on $a_i$, so larger ones allow more.